# Desplegar modal a partir de selección y subforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, formularios

buenas...
Planteo la siguiente uhm cuestión (?

Tengo un formulario, este formulario tiene un apartado de lista donde puedo escoger del 1 al 5, lo que quisiera es saber cómo desplegar un modal a partir de la opción elegida en la que puedo ingresar datos, es decir, escojo el número 2, entonces me despliega un modal, pero este modal tiene dos veces un subformulario...

Sí se escogió el número 1, se despliega un modal que dentro de sí mismo contiene (el subformulario) 3 cajas de texto y un botón.

Escojo la número 2, entonces aparece el modal con 6 cajas de texto y un botón... ¿Me explico?

Un ejemplo sería en un servidor local, se crea la bd, la tabla y cuando se decide ingresar registros te lleva a un espacio donde aparecen cajas de texto según las columnas de la tabla y por debajo hay una opción donde podemos cambiar de 2 a 5 o 10 registros... y se actualiza la página desplegando más espacios para los registros según esa opción...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

P. S. Sí tienen una idea mejor sobre el planteamiento del formulario, también me ayuda...

Comment: Quieres que el contenido del modal que se abre sea distinto según la opción del select, y que éste se abra apenas haces una selección?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es crear un formulario dinámico desde **js**

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo usando fuentes de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) y usando **jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    var numRegs = $("#numRegs").val();
    var modal = $("#myModal");

    // SE CREA EL FORMULARIO
    modal.find(".modal-body").append('<form class="form-group" action="" method="POST">');
    // SE AÑADE LOS ELEMENTOS DEL FORMULARIO SEGÚN EL VALOR DEL SELECT
    for (var i = 1; i <= numRegs; i++) {
      modal.find(".modal-body").append('<h3>Registro ' + i + '</h3>')
      modal.find(".modal-body").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name"/>');
      modal.find(".modal-body").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="description" id="description"    name="description" class="address"/>');
      modal.find(".modal-body").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="tags" id="tags" name="tags"/>');

    }
    // BOTÓN PARA EL FORMULARIO
    modal.find(".modal-body").append('<br><input type="submit" class="form-control" id="savebutton" value="Save" />');
    // FIN DEL FORM
    modal.find(".modal-body").append("</form>");
    modal.modal()
  });

  $("#closeModal").click(function() {
    // AL CERRAR LA MODAL LIMPIA EL CONTENIDO DEL FORMULARIO, ELIMINANDOLO...
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    $("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html("");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>seleccione el número de registros</h2>
    <select class="form-control" id="numRegs">
      <option value=1> 1</option>
      <option value=2> 2</option>
      <option value=3> 3</option>
      <option value=4> 4</option>
      <option value=5> 5</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="closeModal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido en verdad.

Comment: @Vicky_96HV Si te ha solucionado el problema, te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como correcta y así ayudar a más personas en posibles consultas. :D